# Arrays inside a subfigure

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'd like to know how to put an array inside a subfigure (if it can be done). I have no problem putting the following code inside a figure statement but in subfigure it fails miserably and I cannot figure out why. For example this compiled fine:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Input encoding
\usepackage{listings}               % Code Formatting
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math
\usepackage{tikz}                   % TikZ library for graphs
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \[
        \begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
        \tikzmark{a} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \\
        8 & * & 4 \\
        \\
        7 & 6 & 5 \tikzmark{b} \\           
        \end{array}
    \]
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(b.south west)+(0.2,-0.1)$) -- ($(a.north east)+(-0.3,0.2)$);
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But this fails to compile without errors:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Input encoding
\usepackage{listings}               % Code Formatting
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math
\usepackage{tikz}                   % TikZ library for graphs
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{
    \[
        \begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
        \tikzmark{a} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \\
        8 & * & 4 \\
        \\
        7 & 6 & 5 \tikzmark{b} \\       
        \end{array}
    \]
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(b.south west)+(0.2,-0.1)$) -- ($(a.north east)+(-0.3,0.2)$);
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Update, subfig package also does not work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Input encoding
\usepackage{listings}               % Code Formatting
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math
\usepackage{tikz}                   % TikZ library for graphs
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{
    \[
        \begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
        \tikzmark{a} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \\
        8 & * & 4 \\
        \\
        7 & 6 & 5 \tikzmark{b} \\
        \end{array}
    \]
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(b.south west)+(0.2,-0.1)$) -- ($(a.north east)+(-0.3,0.2)$);
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that `subfugure` is deprecated and you should use `subfig` pacakge instead.

Comment: get rid of the blank line within the `array`.  however, since you end the next-to-last line with `\\ `, put in some dummy code, perhaps `\mbox{}` (but if you don't need that blank last line, omit the double backslash from the previous line).

Comment: well you are correct on that, it just a proof of concept; but again I cannot compile it successfully using subfigure, any ideas on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `\[...\]` but `$...$` inside `\subfloat` (I switched to the more reliable `subfig` package, but I guess the same will apply to the obsolete `subfigure`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         % Input encoding
\usepackage{listings}               % Code Formatting
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math
\usepackage{tikz}                   % TikZ library for graphs
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{%
       $ \begin{array}{*{3}{c}}
        \tikzmark{a} 1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \\
        8 & * & 4 \\
        \\
        7 & 6 & 5 \tikzmark{b} \\       
        \end{array}$%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(b.south west)+(0.2,-0.1)$) -- ($(a.north east)+(-0.3,0.2)$);%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I added some `%` characters to prevent spurious blank spaces.

Comment: while we are at it, do you happen to know a way that I can color both the tip and the line of the arrow?

Comment: @jtimz you can add a color to the options for `\draw`, as in `\draw[red,-triangle 45]...`